# Python login to website via twitter

Tags: python, twitter, authorization

A website use 'login via twitter'. Just like this site use facebook. How do I log in and get login cookies for the website (using python), if I know twitter username and password?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general , Twitter doesn't support 'username' and 'password' Authentication. Now, Twitter uses OAuth2 for authentication. There are python-twitter libraries available for this. such as : https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

This could be helpful to You: http://abhi74k.wordpress.com/2010/12/21/tweeting-from-python/

Comment: But how can I use OAuth to authenticate at 3rd party website? My app doesn't work with twitter, it just parse page from the site, avaliable after I authorized there with twitter. Of course, after I manually setup twitter to allow this authentication.

Comment: How OAuth autenticate 3rd party:- You need to register your app with the twitter. They will provide you some credentials (such as consumer keys, consumer secret etc). Now your app is the Consumer. Now consumer will ask for a request token. Request token is a dict which contains oauth token key, oauth secret key etc. Using these two keys you can get access token. By this access token you can authorize. Aceess token is unique for every twitter account. So, you can save this access token for a particular account to use in future. Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't; you use OAuth to authenticate.  Allowing third-party sites to authenticate with a user's username and password is a horrible security flaw, and Twitter no longer allows it.

See Twitter's [OAuth Doc](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter)s for how to authenticate.

EDIT:  Twitter does still maintain an ['xAuth'](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth) option that allows you to authenticate with a username and password.  You need to get special permission from Twitter to use it.